# Android - is setImageResource more efficient that decoding the resource id as a bitmap?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-bitmap

Consider these two code samples for the getView method in a ListView Adapter.
Are they identical memory wise or does setImageResource work more efficiently?

I know that decodeResource creates a new bitmap and eats a bit of memory every time. So if I were to call it enough times with large enough drawbles it would cause out of memory error. But I couldn't find with setImageResource works in the source code.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
     img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),resIds[position]));
     return img;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
     img.setImageResource(resIds[position]) ;
     return img;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says in the docs

> This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI
>   thread, which can cause a latency hiccup.

Furthermore, it says

> If that's a concern, consider using setImageDrawable() 
>   or setImageBitmap() and android.graphics.BitmapFactory instead.

This already implies an answer to your question: no, it is not more efficient. To save memory and runtime, store the result of the BitmapFactory (or Drawable) and take care that it is not executed every time the ImageView is set.